# Using python to click items on a page with text changing javascript and be able to parse the new information

Tags: javascript, python, html, parsing, scripting

I am looking to find a way to code a script in python that can click all the items in my Steam inventory. For those who do not know what that is here is an example:

http://steamcommunity.com/id/timetoidle5/inventory/#753_0

Ideally it should be able to click each of the links and parse the new information that it gets. Ie. it should be able to find the difference between the different Left 4 Dead 2 cards.

I have done some research and I have been told that downloading the selenium module may be the best way to deal with javascript on a webpage. Although I am still not entirely sure what the best way is. I have heard that mechanize may work as well, but is made for static webpages (webpages with little to no javascript?).

I was hoping also for some tips/steps on how to get started on something like this. I already have some experience with HTML and CSS so I know my way around the syntax and currently I am quickly reading through a Javascript book. I also have done some Python scripting in the past and taken a few introductory courses on it.

Comment: Use Selenium. The only tips I can give you - use Google to find tutorial.

Comment: For a less general approach, take a look at [steamapi](https://github.com/smiley/steamapi) which is a Python wrapper around [Steam's own web API](http://steamcommunity.com/dev)